Mixing auto implemented accessor with an explicit accessor
Has an auto-implemented get accessor with a bodied set accessor always been an error ?
internal class MyClass
{        
internal int robot;
internal int Robot { get; set { this.robot = value; } }
}

The error is CS8652 The feature 'field keyword' is currently in Preview and "unsupported".
Context: Visual Studio 2022, Target DotNet 8.
There is no error if both get and set are auto-implemented. There is no error if both get and set have bodies.

There is a preview feature in C# 13 that allows you do do what you want: field - Field backed property declarations.  Other than that, in released .NET / C# versions nothing has changed since the C# 3 question, a property must be either automatic or manual, no mixing.  So yes it has always been an error.

For the C# 14 preview functionality, see this answer by ˈvɔlə to C# 11: "field" keyword not supported in VS 2022.  Does that answer your question?

@IvanPetrov yes it's the same question but mine is terse. It's better that way.

@dbc Your comment would be better posted as an answer.

@H2ONaCl yeah, a duplicate...
